# Symfony2 Filter Table with KnpPaginator

Tags: symfony, filter, html-table

I am trying to filter a HTML-Table I build wit KnpPaginator.

In their docs they tell you it would be possible to Filter: [Possibility to add custom filtering, sorting functionality depending on request parameters](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle).

My current solution looks like this:
I read the request parameters myself and adjust the query by hand. However I would love to be able to Filter my whole table without adding my own logic for every column (My Table has more than 50 columns!).

Is this possible by default or do you have any other solutions available?

Maybe it would be even possible to use a Plugin like this: [Filterable](http://lightswitch05.github.io/filterable/).

**Edit:**
All right after some research I found this post at the [Github Page of the Paginator](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/issues/25). However I still hope there could be anything else?